# Sonar 2.13.1 with MySQL 5.1 Issue

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

We are new to Sonar and just downloaded v2.13.1 and got it up and working with our project. It was great until it started running slowly and I realized it was because we were still running on the included Derby. We are running MySQL Server 5.1 on the same box (along with TeamCity CI), so I followed the steps to setup MySQL.

- I ran `extras\database\mysql\create_database.sql` to create the sonar user and assign permissions.
- I updated `conf\sonar.properties` to include:

  ```
  sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
  sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  sonar.jdbc.validationQuery:                select 1
  ```
- I restarted the Sonar server and saw from the logs that the database tables were created and I can confirm this independently by browsing the database.
- When I start the server, I get the following in the log:

  ```
  2012.02.07 13:50:58 INFO  o.s.c.p.Database  Create JDBC datasource
  2012.02.07 13:51:01 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Initializing Hibernate
  2012.02.07 13:51:11 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Start services...
  ```
- When I run our TeamCity configuration that does a "`mvn clean install`" followed by a  "`mvn sonar:sonar`" goal, which previously worked under Derby, our build completes successfully, but Sonar dies with the following information:

  ```
  [14:11:24] [west-chai:my-project] [INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) @ my-project ---
  [14:11:26] [west-chai:my-project] [INFO] Sonar version: 2.13.1
  [14:11:29] [west-chai:my-project] [WARN] [14:11:29.403] Derby database should be used for evaluation purpose only
  [14:11:29] [west-chai:my-project] [INFO] [14:11:29.403] Create JDBC datasource
  [14:11:30] [west-chai:my-project] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project my-project: Can not execute Sonar
  [14:11:30] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [14:11:30] [INFO] Reactor Summary:
  [14:11:30] [INFO] 
  [14:11:24] [west-chai:my-project] [INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) @ my-project ---
  [14:11:26] [west-chai:my-project] [INFO] Sonar version: 2.13.1
  [14:11:29] [west-chai:my-project] [WARN] [14:11:29.403] Derby database should be used for evaluation purpose only
  [14:11:29] [west-chai:my-project] [INFO] [14:11:29.403] Create JDBC datasource
  [14:11:30] [west-chai:my-project] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project my-project: Can not execute Sonar
  [14:11:30] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [14:11:30] [INFO] Reactor Summary:
  [14:11:30] [INFO] 
  [14:11:30] [INFO] PROJECT COMPONENT 1 ................... FAILURE [34.679s]
  [14:11:30] [INFO] PROJECT COMPONENT 2 ................... SKIPPED
  ...
  [14:11:30] [INFO] PROJECT COMPONENT N ................... SKIPPED
  [14:11:30] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [14:11:30] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
  [14:11:30] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [14:11:30] [INFO] Total time: 41.809s
  [14:11:30] [INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 07 14:11:30 CST 2012
  [14:11:31] [INFO] Final Memory: 31M/92M
  [14:11:31] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [14:11:31] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project my-project: Can not execute Sonar: PicoLifecycleException: method 'public final org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start()', instance 'org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchDatabase@1d4d6a, java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapper: Fail to connect to database: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.) -> [Help 1]
  [14:11:31] [ERROR] 
  [14:11:31] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
  [14:11:31] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
  [14:11:31] [ERROR] 
  [14:11:31] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
  [14:11:31] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
  [14:11:31] Process exited with code 1
  [14:11:31] [Publishing artifacts] Paths to publish: [E:\apps\TeamCity\server\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\.tc-maven-bi\maven-build-info.1.xml.gz => .teamcity]
  [14:11:31] [Publishing artifacts] Sending files
  [14:11:31] Step Sonar (Maven) failed
  [14:11:31] Waiting for 38 service processes to complete
  [14:11:31] Sending build.finish.properties.gz file
  [14:11:31] Paths to publish: [MyProject\Mainline\MyApp\target\chai.war, MyProject\Mainline\MyComponent\MyComponent-service\target\MyComponent.war]
  [14:11:31] Sending files
  [14:11:35] Build finished
  [14:11:30] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [14:11:30] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
  [14:11:30] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [14:11:30] [INFO] Total time: 41.809s
  [14:11:30] [INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 07 14:11:30 CST 2012
  [14:11:31] [INFO] Final Memory: 31M/92M
  [14:11:31] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [14:11:31] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project my-project: Can not execute Sonar: PicoLifecycleException: method 'public final org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start()', instance 'org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchDatabase@1d4d6a, java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapper: Fail to connect to database: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.) -> [Help 1]
  [14:11:31] [ERROR] 
  [14:11:31] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
  [14:11:31] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
  [14:11:31] [ERROR] 
  [14:11:31] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
  [14:11:31] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
  [14:11:31] Process exited with code 1
  [14:11:31] [Publishing artifacts] Paths to publish: [E:\apps\TeamCity\server\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\.tc-maven-bi\maven-build-info.1.xml.gz => .teamcity]
  [14:11:31] [Publishing artifacts] Sending files
  [14:11:31] Step Sonar (Maven) failed
  [14:11:31] Waiting for 38 service processes to complete
  [14:11:31] Sending build.finish.properties.gz file
  [14:11:31] Paths to publish: [MyProject\Mainline\MyApp\target\chai.war, MyProject\Mainline\MyComponent\MyComponent-service\target\MyComponent.war]
  [14:11:31] Sending files
  [14:11:35] Build finished
  ```

The error line that follows mentions port 1527, which is referenced by the commented out Derby config lines.

```
    [14:11:31] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project my-project: Can not execute Sonar: PicoLifecycleException: method 'public final org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start()', instance 'org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchDatabase@1d4d6a, java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapper: Fail to connect to database: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.) -> [Help 1]
```

If I comment out the `sonar.jdbc` lines above and restore the following lines, then the both our "`mvn clean install`" and the "`mvn sonar:sonar`" complete successfully.

```
sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:derby://localhost:152/sonar;create=true
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
sonar.jdbc.validationQuery:                values(1)
```

**Is there a different configuration for the Maven target than what is used directly by the Sonar server? Is there an explicit way to tell which JDBC datasource is being connected to?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Sonar server and your Maven client are configured separately.

Unless configured otherwise Maven will automatically assume that Sonar is running locally with a Derby database, explaining your errors.

The [Sonar documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE51/Analyzing+with+Maven) explains how Maven can be configured to support MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the similar problem yesterday (April, 11 2012)
1) input:

- teamcity 7
- maven 3.0.4
- sonar 2.13
- postgresql 9
- global maven settings.xml contains sonar profile with proper DB settings
- jdk 1.6.30
- project build from command line passed ok

2) result:

- teamcity - Can not execute Sonar
- log contains exception

  ```
  Fail to connect to database: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (java.net.ConnectException : Ошибка соединения с сервером localhost на порту 1527
  ```

3) possible cause:

- TeamCity uses wrong settings.xml

4) solution:

- goto Administratioin
- goto left menu Integrations->Maven settings
- upload your version of settings.xml (in my case with proper settings for Sonar)